# Why my Condition in PHP doesn't work?

Tags: php, mysql

Hello guys this is my PHP code that I written for decrease the "Credit" table on MySQL when people use from their Credit for buying facilities. But I want when their "Credit" is 0 they get Error that "Your Credit is not Enough , Please Buy a Credit" . But I see "echo" doesn't give this error ! What is the problem in my code ?

```
<?php
if (session_id() == "")
{
   session_start();
}
if (!isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
   $accessdenied_page = '';
   header('Location: '.$accessdenied_page);
   exit;
}
$mysql_server = 'localhost';
$mysql_username = '*******';
$mysql_password = '******';
$mysql_database = '******';
$mysql_table = 'details2';
$success_page = 'League.php';
$username = 'username';
$db = mysql_connect($mysql_server, $mysql_username, $mysql_password);
      if (!$db)
      {
         die('Failed to connect to database server!<br>'.mysql_error());
      }
      mysql_select_db($mysql_database, $db) or die('Failed to select database<br>'.mysql_error());

$sql = "UPDATE `".$mysql_table."` SET `Credit` = `Credit` - 20  WHERE `username` = `".$username."` AND `Credit` >= 20";

mysql_query($sql, $db);


header('Location: '.$success_page);
exit;
?>
```

Comment: An `UPDATE` is not a `SELECT`, in other words: It doesn't return data. Use a `SELECT` to get the credit left. Also, you would want to have enough credit to get 20, like this: `Credit = IF(Credit > 20, Credit - 20, Credit)`.

Comment: aw it means I should write separately another for "SELECT" , true ? @KIKOSoftware

Comment: Yes, better still, first use a select to get the credit, use PHP to see if the user had enough and only update when that's the case. That way your update is simpler, and not used when there's not enough credit.

Comment: other parts of my code for "echo" is completely true ? @KIKOSoftware

Comment: You should not be using mysql_query - research (and use) mysqli_query.

Comment: I don't understand your last comment. Please note that the mysql extension of PHP is deprecated (shouldn't be used), use mysqli or PDO.

Comment: ok , Thanks @CFPSupport

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Just I should add "i" after all sql , true ?

Comment: No, no, of course not. You should check the manual carefully and understand exactly what you're doing. Read, learn, test and try. Never do the lazy thing.

Comment: @Martijn what did you edit ??!! Now you did help with this edited ??!! lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
if (session_id() == "")
{
   session_start();
} 
if (!isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
   $accessdenied_page = '';
   header('Location: '.$accessdenied_page);
   exit;
}

// NOTE: your $username should be reflected in the actual username from the User...
$username = 'username';    
$success_page = './League.php';
$dbservername = 'localhost';
$dbusername = 'bceus_user';
$dbpassword = 'password';
$dbname = 'bceus_data';
$dbtable = 'details2';
$conn = new mysqli($dbservername, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
$sql = "Select Credit from `".$dbtable."` WHERE `username` = `".$username."`";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        if ($row['Credit'] < 20) {
            echo "Your Credit is not Enough , Please Buy a Credit";
        }    
        else {
           $sql2 = "update `".$dbtable."` set Credit = Credit - 20 WHERE `username` = `".$username."`";
           $conn->query($sql2);
        }
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
header('Location: '.$success_page);
exit;
?>
```

Comment: Apart from the correct select, there are at least two problems with this code. Firstly, there's no update when there's enough credit, and secondly, what does the `($Result < 1)` do in your opinion? Think about a situation in which a user wants 20 credits.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware - while the update is in the OP code, that doesn't appear to be the issue - the OP missed the basic (and also asked in the question) about not getting the error about 0 credits - not about fixing the entire code logic (which will need more info on just how that happens, etc.  Admittedly, I haven't worked with mysql statements in so long, I missed the fact it was only the query (embarrassed emoticon here...) - I'll fix it....

Comment: @CFPSupport This code I tried its not true , it gives error : `$sql = "Select Credits from `".$mysql_table."` WHERE `username` = `".$username."`";

$Result = mysql_query($sql, $db);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($Result)) {
if ($Result < 1) {
    echo "Your Credit is not Enough , Please Buy a Credit";
}    
mysql_free_result($result);`

Comment: @CFPSupport I edited my above code to true style , Just now how can I put condition for it gives error if the Credit was not enough , and also I want our clients can't buy any items till again buy a enough Credit.

Comment: @CFPSupport Error of code was that one part of your code needed to be edited in true style , maybe something you forgot to add as ` or " or anything else

Comment: I have no idea what that 'true style' stuff means - either you see an error message (and tell what that is) or don't.......  I edited to add your connection data - maybe that is what you are asking (please be specific on errors, etc. - otherwise, it makes it very difficult to help)

Comment: I've now edited my answer to show the full page as you had - and included a NOTE about an issue that you must correct on your end.  If this (or other answer) answers your question, please mark it as accepted.  If not, please be clear on error messages, etc.  We are here and trying to help, but you must also take some responsibility for 1) asking clear questions and 2) utilizing the help, not expecting someone to do the work for you.

Comment: @CFPSupport Your procedure is true that firstly you did SELECT and then you put Condition and after that UPDATE , but I wanted you guide me in my PHP 5 version style similar my code.

Answer (score 1):

**First i will address your initial problem**

The problem you encounter is, that you `UPDATE` query is built in a way, that it always update the table. If we take a closer look to the individual parts you can see the difference.

```
SET `Credit` = IF(Credit > 0, Credit - 20, 0)
```

In the `SET` part you overwrite the value in the `Credit` column based in the if condition. The if condition always returns a value. If `Credit` has a value of 0 or less, it will be overwritten to 0, while it will be decreased by 20 in all other cases. This means there is an update in any case.

```
WHERE `username` = $username
```

The where clause limits the rows that are overwritten, but just compares the `username` column to the given username.

So to limit your `UPDATE` to only those rows, that have the given username and the fitting amount of credits, you would need to pack both conditions into the `WHERE` block of your `UPDATE` query:

```
UPDATE table 
SET `Credit` = `Credit` - 20 
WHERE `username` = $username AND `Credit` >= 20;
```

With this condition only those rows will be updated, that contain the given username and also  have enough credits.

**Further problems**

You are using deprecated database functions. This means, that those functions do not fulfill todays standards. You should learn about [mysqli prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) or [PDO prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) to use modern tools.

Comment: Thanks @PhilippMaurer

Comment: Your guidance could really help me so much

Comment: How can i put condition in PHP that If the Credit is not enough It gives error and also they can't buy any facilities with their Credit? @PhilippMaurer

Comment: @Jeyson You can keep your code. Just update your sql functions and the update query